# Error installing Nokogiri on Ubuntu 15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri

The Nokigiri installation fails when running `bundle install` with the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
```

I installed libxml2, still it's throwing the error.

I could install the gem with the command

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2
```

but it fails when I run `bundle install`.

Comment: Do you have xcode installed? Are you on Mac OSX? Are you installing these on a system level or using Homebrew?

Comment: No, I'm running Ubuntu 15.

Comment: Are you sure the include path `/usr/include/libxml2/` is correct?

Comment: @virtuexru didn't double check cause it did install when i ran it.

Comment: Make sure that path is correct otherwise it won't know where to look for the libxml2 installation and will then fail.

Comment: It had something to do with the rails version I was running. Had to downgrade it to  install it.